# PHP7. Reflection doesn't work from old versions php

Tags: reflection, php-7

I have a php script which was written on php 5.6.19, works on 5.3 version to, with some installed addons.

I decide to try execute it on php7.

The special of the script that I am initializing a class with parameter by reference via creating a new instance with `Reflection::class`. And there warning then waited variable by reference but value received.

Definition of the class' constructor method tried to create an instance from:

```
public function __construct($user, IDatabase &$repository, $errors = null);
```

Sample of code where this constructor is used:

```
// define manager type to create (all managers has the same constructor)
$manager = $managersNamespace . ucfirst($this->_manager) . "Manager";
// trying to create the manager
// !!!And here a Warning occurs
$reflect = new \ReflectionClass($manager);
$manager = $reflect->newInstance($user, $database, $errors);
```

After these I am invoking a method I need, and here the fatal error with stopped the script:

```
$method = "show" . ucfirst($this->_page) . "Page";
$reflect->getMethod($method)->invoke($manager);
```

I didn't see any changes in documentation. Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Instead of a coupla disconnected code snippets, can you give us an SSCCE that demonstrates the precise problem, and only the problem, so we can run it comparatively?

Comment: I tried to guess what a SSCCE for this might be - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a32f440e3939f845a9b1c26bc2f06408abbf5cd - and it worked A-OK on both 5.6 and 7.0. Can you take that code and revise it to reflect your actual situation and post THAT as an example in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, why are you passing an object by reference !?

Objects have pass-by-reference semantics, forcibly trying to pass objects by reference has not made good sense since *PHP 4*.

Just remove the `&` ...

Let's ignore that, and pretend there is still a problem, so that you can try to understand what is going on.

To break down the problem, first you need to understand the distinction between a variable and an expression:

```
mine(1 + 2);
```

The argument to mine has no name, it's represented by a temporary variable in the engine: it's an expression.

```
mine(1);
```

The argument to mine has no name, it's not an expression, but a literal constant, represented by a compiler variable in the engine. It's similar to a temporary variable, a kind of constant expression.

```
mine($a);
```

The argument to mine has a name, which you can use to refer to it's value. It's a normal variable.

*Only variables can be passed by reference because you cannot refer to expressions or literal constants*

Next you need to understand why we pass-by-reference:

```
function mine(int $thing) {
    $thing++;
}

$a = 1;

mine($a);

var_dump($a); // int(1)
```

In this code, `$a` is passed to `mine()` by value, so that the changes that `mine()` make to `$thing` are only visible inside the scope of `mine`. `$a` is unchanged after the call to `mine()` returns because `$a` and `$thing` are distinct, having been passed-by-value, which means it's value was copied on to the call stack for the invocation of `mine()`.

```
function mine(int &$thing) {
    $thing++;
}

$a = 1;

mine($a);

var_dump($a); // int(2)
```

In the code above, `$a` is passed to `mine()` by reference, this means that `$a` and `$thing` are no longer distinct. The changes `mine()` make to `$thing` are now visible after the call to `mine()` returns.

The last piece in the puzzle is Reflection:

```
function mine(int &$thing) {
    $thing++;
}

$a = 1;

$reflector = new ReflectionFunction("mine");
$reflector->invoke($a);
```

The code above will raise:

```
Warning: Parameter 1 to mine() expected to be a reference, value given in /usr/src/php-src/refs.php on line 9
```

This is because `ReflectionFunction::invoke` and similar reflection functions (`ReflectionClass::newInstance`) [accept their parameters by value](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP-7.1/ext/reflection/php_reflection.c#1961) and [pass them onto the invoked function by value](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP-7.1/ext/reflection/php_reflection.c#1970).

## But ...

There is still a difference between pass-by-reference *semantics*, and passing by reference, a dangerous one:

```
class Foo {
    public function qux() {}
}

class Bar {}

function mine(Foo &$foo) {
  $foo = new Bar();        
}

$foo = new Foo;

mine($foo);

$foo->qux();
```

Will obviously yield:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Bar::qux() in /usr/src/php-src/refs.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /usr/src/php-src/refs.php on line 16
```

The declaration of `mine()` tells lies about the type safety of it's parameter. Type safety is only guaranteed upon entry to the function, the function body is free to break type safety, but it doesn't usually affect the caller when relying on the engines pass by reference semantics for objects.

This is an extremely scary kind of API, that should be avoided.